# Meaning of matrix 'diag' operator with matrix arguments

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, block-matrices

I came across this definition in a paper and can't figure out what it is supposed to represent:

[image: The definition]

I understand that there is a 'diag' operator which when given a vector argument creates a matrix with the vector values along the diagonal, but I can't understand how such an operator would work on a set of matrices.

Comment: Are you familiar with block matrices?  If you read it as block matrices, it makes sense.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

$\operatorname{diag}$ with matrix arguments creates a *block-diagonal* matrix. If, say, $A$ is an $M$ by $M$ matrix, and $B$ is $N$ by $N$, then

$$\operatorname{diag}(A,B) = \begin{pmatrix} A & 0_{M,N} \\ 0_{N,M} & B\end{pmatrix},$$

where $0_{M,N}$ is the $M$ by $N$ matrix of zeros.

Comment: Is there any meaning to $diag(A)$ with no second argument?

Comment: Not that I know of. It has to be a list of matrix or a vector.

Comment: @JoshBone I see ofter in books the use of $\boldsymbol a=diag(\boldsymbol A)$ meaning that the vector $\boldsymbol a$ has the terms of the diagonal of the matrix $\boldsymbol A$.

Comment: @IvoTebexreni that's exactly what I was looking for, thanks!